# Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported in Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, provider

I use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for converting Excel files to database,
and I get this error:

> Cannot start a transaction for OLE DB provider
>
> "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)". OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"  returned
>   message "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is
>   supported

When I run profiler on server I see these commands runs:

```
declare @p7 int
set @p7=NULL

exec sp_executesql N'EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[SYSMain_ExcelImport] 
@ExcelPath  =  @p0, @StoredProcedure = @p1, @SheetName = @p2,
@DoneByPersonID = @p3',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000),
@p3 int,@RETURN_VALUE int output',
@p0=N'
E:\TolueCRM\TolueCRM\upload  \SYSMain_ExcelReadyForImport 57\3.xlsx'
,@p1=N'SYSMain_Excel_SendigRecievingDebitCustomer',
@p2=N'sheet1',@p3=101,@RETURN_VALUE=@p7 output
select @p7
```

Which when I run it in Management Studio directly I get no error and it works correctly.

Then profiler show this command:

```
exec sp_reset_connection
```

then :

```
-- network protocol: LPC
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level serializable
```

I guess setting for isolation level serializable causes this error
and last: the error message was create:

```
declare @p8 int
set @p8=1
exec sp_executesql 
N'EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[SYSMainSproc_EntitiesAllField_Update] 
@ID = @p0,   @IDVAlue = @p1, @Entity = @p2, @strset = @p3,
@DoneByPersonID = @p4',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 int,@p2 nvarchar(4000)
,@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p4 int,
@RETURN_VALUE int   output',
@p0=N'SYSMain_ExcelReadyForImportID',
@p1=57,@p2=N'SYSMain_ExcelReadyForImport',
@p3=N' Description=
N''Cannot start a transaction for OLE DB provider
"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for   linked server "(null)".
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" 
returned message   
"Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is    supported.".''',
@p4=101,@RETURN_VALUE=@p8 output
select @p8
```

I guess provider can't work in serializable isolation level but I don't know which part sets the isolation level to serializable.

Let me add something else: this error sometimes does not happen! And when I convert by application works right!

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show some relevant code? How are you executing this procedures? Are you using [`TransactionScope`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx)?

Comment: thanks martin for your reply, 
in fact i don't write this application i'm just debugging, but i found TransactionScope is used, is the problem related to it?

Comment: Quite possibly. As per the link above this defaults to serializable if you don't specify otherwise.

Comment: I explicitly set the isolation level to read committed  in procedure and problem solved, thanks Martin

Comment: @MehdyMoini i'm having the same problem what's the solution here?